# How to fetch pipeline id of a datapipeline using aws cli

Tags: command-line-interface, amazon-data-pipeline

Folks,

I'm trying to automate the process of creating aws datapipelines, I am stuck on how to fetch pipeline id of an existing datapipeline using aws cli. Idea is to trigger a jenkins job and get the pipeline created using the pipeline definition, parameter and values json files, The values.json file will be changed as on when need to create different pipelines.

**Approach:**

1. Create a datapipeline using aws cli create-pipeline operation.

   **aws datapipeline create-pipeline --name my-pipeline --unique-id my-pipeline-token**
2. Populate/configure datapipeline using put-pipeline-definition
   operation.

   **aws datapipeline put-pipeline-definition --pipeline-id id ...**

The issue here is, When i create a pipeline, AWS randomly generates the pipelineId. Due to which we cannot predict the id and feed it to put-pipeline-definition operation.

After i issue create-pipeline and list the pipline

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-10-10 ~]$  aws datapipeline list-pipelines | grep -B 1 "my-dtpl-001"
            "id": "df-034643278897334HARB",
            "name": "my-dtpl-001"
```

'**df-034643278897334HARB**' is my desired value. I can do some unix cut/tr stuff, but that may not be a neat solution i believe. if not i have to live with it this way.
In case anyone of you have automated process already, Kindly share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

The `create-pipeline` command will return [json output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/datapipeline/create-pipeline.html) like this:

```
{
    "pipelineId": "df-08361192IO3ML9Q6X5EQ"
}
```

You can parse this output and extract the pipeline ID in a script using the `jq` tool:

```
DPL_ID=`aws datapipeline create-pipeline --name ... --unique-id ... | jq -r .pipelineId`
aws datapipeline put-pipeline-definition --pipeline-id ${DPL_ID} ...
```

`jq` should be available on most AWS Linux instances. You can find more documentation on the syntax [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually if found the answer, The neat way of fetching the datapipeline id a datapipeline.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-3-999 ~]$ aws datapipeline list-pipelines --output text|grep "mydatapipeline"|awk '{print $2}'
df-1050199PW1VR4WVJ1SN
```

This page has the best explanation of controlling your output, 
[Formatting your AWS Cli output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get the pipeline id by the name we can use the AWS cli built-in JSON-based output filtering capabilities with the `--query` [option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter).

```
aws datapipeline list-pipelines --query "pipelineIdList[?name=='YOUR_PIPELINE_NAME'].id" --output text
```

Should give you a result of something like this:

```
df-1234567ABCDEVXXXXX
```